# What is the backward process of max operation in deep learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, pytorch

I know that the backward process of deep learning follows the gradient descent algorithm. However, there is never a gradient concept for `max` operation.

How does deep learning frameworks like tensorflow, pytorch deal with the backward of 'max' operation like `maxpooling`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to think of  what the `max` operator actually does? That is:

- **It returns or lets better say it propagates the maximum.**

And that's exactly what it does here - it takes two or more tensors and propagates forward *(only)* the maximum.

It is often helpful to take a look at a short example:

```py
t1 = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True)
t2 = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True)


s1 = torch.sum(t1)
s2 = torch.sum(t2)
print('sum t1:', s1, 'sum t2:', s2)
m = torch.max(s1, s2)
print('max:', m, 'requires_grad:', m.requires_grad)
m.backward()
print('t1 gradients:', t1.grad)
print('t2 gradients:', t2.grad)
```

This code creates two random tensors sums them up and puts them through a max function. Then `backward()` is called upon the result.

Lets take a look at the two possible outcomes:

- Outcome 1 - sum of `t1` is larger:

  ```py
  sum t1: tensor(5.6345) sum t2: tensor(4.3965)
  max: tensor(5.6345) requires_grad: True
  t1 gradients: tensor([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
  t2 gradients: tensor([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
  ```
- Outcome 2 - sum of `t2` is larger:

  ```py
  sum t1: tensor(3.3263) sum t2: tensor(4.0517)
  max: tensor(4.0517) requires_grad: True
  t1 gradients: tensor([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
  t2 gradients: tensor([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
  ```

As you would expect in the case `s1` represents the maximum gradients will be calculated for `t1`. Similarly when `s2` is the maximum gradients will be calculated for `t2`.

- **Similarly like in the forward step, back propagation is propagating backwards through the maximum.**

---

One thing worth mentioning is that the other **tensors** which **do not represent** the **maximum are still part of the graph**. Only the gradients are set to zero then. If they wouldn't be part of the graph you would get `None` as gradient, instead of a zero vector.

You can check what happens if you use python-`max` instead of `torch.max`:

```py
t1 = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True)
t2 = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True)


s1 = torch.sum(t1)
s2 = torch.sum(t2)
print('sum t1:', s1, 'sum t2:', s2)
m = max(s1, s2)
print('max:', m, 'requires_grad:', m.requires_grad)
m.backward()
print('t1 gradients:', t1.grad)
print('t2 gradients:', t2.grad)
```

Output:

```py
sum t1: tensor(4.7661) sum t2: tensor(4.4166)
max: tensor(4.7661) requires_grad: True
t1 gradients: tensor([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
t2 gradients: None
```

Comment: Excellent answer, especially for the " the other tensors which do not represent the maximum are still part of the graph".